# Bad SVG performance on Ipad

Tags: performance, ipad, svg, d3.js

I am rendering 3000 SVG circles using D3.js. D3.js works great, but y need to move them using mouse. On my Safari desktop works great, but, when I render them on Ipad ... well, from 15 FPS go down to 2/1 FPS.

If I just render 500 circles ... steel poor. Is there any way to have a better performance?

I am moving them using this:

```
var diff = this.lastClientX - getD3MousePosition().X;
            if(isNumber(diff)){
                this.XLines.forEach(function(line){
                    line.attr("x1",parseFloat(line.attr("x1")) - diff);
                    line.attr("x2",parseFloat(line.attr("x2")) - diff);
                })
            }
            this.lastClientX = getD3MousePosition().X;
```

- Diff is just a variable to get last mouse move.
- getD3MousePosition() give you mouseX and mouseY position.
- this.Xlines has jquery references to each SVG circle, collected from D£.js once it render them.

Basically, I want to move 3000 SVG circles on a fluid way on Ipad.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a code exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/todotresde/nM4B9/

Comment: Don't know if you ever got this to go faster, but for one thing I'd drop down to native DOM methods by turning line.attr into line[0][0].getAttribute() to avoid the D3 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3 transformations. Instead of changing the SVG position attributes, you can translate the points with CSS3 transformations. This will likely be smoother on the iPad.

If that doesn't work well enough: you could try using HTML5 Canvas instead of SVG for better rendering performance. D3 has Canvas support for rendering.

Comment: That, or just use svg `transform` attributes for moving things around. But touching 3000 attributes is still not optimal, so try to apply the transform to a group of circles if they don't need to move individually.